# How to exclude folders from c++ core guidelines checkers check path?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-analysis, exclusionpath

My problem is that the Nuget packages (inside solutions /packages folder) are causing a lot of warnings and analyzing them is taking ages.

I have tried excluding folders from static analysis with no success. I have an understanding that this would be achieved using a CAExcludePath enviroment variable. But where should I set the CAExcludePath environment variable? I have already tried setting it through project->debugger->environment field.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @thomthom I did not. I still use smart_ptrs. I think if I tried again I would separate the code to check in a separate project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767445/1023911

Answer (score 1):

The variable is accessible in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets` and its value can be seen by increasing build output verbosity (`Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity to 'Diagnostic'`). Setting the variable did **not** helped me with the issue though. Edit: I'm using MSVS Professional 2017 ver 15.2 (26430.15)