# How can you exclude third-party libraries from CppCoreCheck?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, cpp-core-guidelines

I started to use CppCoreCheck on some of my projects.  Hurray!

But now I'm stuck in a gazillion warnings from boost and Qt.  Is there a way to exclude them from the check?

Comment: Similar issue reported [under another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245700/how-to-exclude-folders-from-c-core-guidelines-checkers-check-path/45140499#45140499).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767445/1023911